# How to insert a new character in a StringStream and extract to string within a loop in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, cstring, stringstream

I am not sure what the issue is with my code. I would like for the character to be updated and inserted into the stringstream on each iteration of the for-loop and extracted to a string that I can later use to append to a char[] variable. The output I wish to receive for the variable content is: 
What does CPU stand for?
A. Central Processing Unit
B. Control Programming Unit
C. Central Proramming Unit
D. Control Processing Unit 
Instead I get all A's down the line. How do I update the value in the stream so that temp takes on the values "A.", "B.", "C.", and "D.". I am not new to C++ but I am new to using stringstream. Can anyone explain what is happening and how I may be able to work around it? I am using a g++ compiler in a Unix environment.

```
    char content[1096];
    int numOfChoices;
    char letterChoice = 'A';
    string choice, temp;
    stringstream ss;

    strcpy ( content, "What does CPU stand for?");
    cout << "How many multiple choice options are there? ";
    cin >> numOfChoices;
    cin.ignore(8, '\n'); 
    for (int i = numOfChoices; i > 0; i--)
    {
       strcat (content, "\n");
       ss << letterChoice << ".";
       ss >> temp;
       strcat(content, temp.c_str());
       ss.str("");
       cout << "Enter answer for multiple choice option " 
            << letterChoice++ <<":\n--> ";
       getline (cin, choice);
       strcat(content, " ");
       strcat(content, choice.c_str());
     }
       cout << content << endl;
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you have all those ugly c-string operations in there? You hardly _try_ to use the `stringstream`.

Comment: I just needed the stringstream in order to build a string that included a char that I can increment depending on how many multiple choice options the user wanted to enter. I started out using c-strings then discovered the stringstream after.

Comment: I did try using the stringstream throughout, but for some reason it wasn't appending the information I wanted it to on each iteration of the for loop, while strcat gave me no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform insertion and extraction, you should always check whether it was successful or not:

**Example**

```
if (!(ss << letterChoice << "."))
{
    cout << "Insertion failed!" << endl;
}
```

That way, you can know right away that something went wrong.
In the first loop, when you do `ss >> temp;` it extracts all the characters in the stream and puts them into `temp`. However, the end of file is reached so the eofbit gets set. So, on the next loop when you do `ss << letterChoice << ".";`, the operation fails because the eofbit is set. If you add an `ss.clear();` after `ss >> temp;` the code will work because you reset the stream state after eofbit is set.

However, you don't need `stringstream` or all those old C functions in your code. You could do everything with `std::string` like so:

```
string content = "";
int numOfChoices;
char letterChoice = 'A';
string choice;

content += "What does CPU stand for?";
cout << "How many multiple choice options are there? ";
cin >> numOfChoices;
cin.ignore(8, '\n'); 
for (int i = numOfChoices; i > 0; i--)
{
   content += "\n";
   content += letterChoice;
   content += ".";
   cout << "Enter answer for multiple choice option " 
        << letterChoice++ <<":\n--> ";
   getline (cin, choice);
   content += " ";
   content += choice;
 }
 cout << content << endl;
```

Comment: Good explanation as well. I understand!

Comment: @user1457479: The most important thing to learn is to always perform "error checking/handling". Many people omit checking out of laziness, etc., but when something goes wrong, it can save you a lot of pain in the future (also, don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answers the question).

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that you could concatenate with strings with chars